# Does attaching to a process make it behave differently?

Tags: c, debugging

While I am aware of the differences between debug and release builds, I am curious if attaching the debugger to a process (built release or debug) changes that processes behaviour?

For reference, I'm developing on HP 11.31 Itanium but still am curious for the general case.

Comment: @ojblass: Hi, rewrote your Q for more clarity. Hope you are OK with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug

Of course, attaching a debugger will change the timing (which can change e.g. thread race conditions), and also some system calls can detect if a debugger is attached.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can, depending on the platform and the method of debugging.  For example, when [debugging on Windows](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1893), there is actually the [IsDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(VS.85).aspx) function.  As noted that function can be circumvented, but then there are other means.  So basically, it's complicated.

Comment: Waht you are saying is that it's possible for an application to find out, but I doubt that's what the questioner wanted to know.  It's much more useful to explain many ways in which an application can act differently *without intending to*, since that's the case that most often comes up in debugging.

Comment: The question wasn't specific regarding intentional/unintentional changes of behavior.  As you note, there can be both.  Other answerers have delve a little into the mechanisms of unintentional changes in debug mode.  As noted, it is relatively common that the slower diagnostic memory allocator is also a little more forgiving of certain errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, lots of things inside the Windows data structures change when a debugger is attached. It changes how memory is allocated/freed, it adds additional housekeeping code and "markers" on the stack (Ever noticed the F00D values in newly allocated memory) in fact many of the changes are used by anti-debuggers to detect if an application is being debugged.

In interpreted languages (Java, .NET) the runtime will often generate different machine instructions when running under a debugger to help it trap and display exceptions, show the original code, etc. It will usually generate unoptimized code as well when a debugger is attached.

Some of these changes affect the way the software behaves and can result complicate transient bugs that are caused by optimizations or extremely fine timinig dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've often found that attaching a debugger to a process instantly makes bugs disappear, only to have them reappear when I compile my app in release mode. Unfortunately I usually can't really ask all my users to open a debugger just to run my app, so it can be quite frustrating.

Comment: Have you attached the debugger to a release version or did you compile with debug flags?

Comment: Compilation with debug flags often makes memory behave a little different.  I am curious about the act of attaching the debugger.  I am not really after the effect of debug vs. release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is that for multithreaded apps attaching the debugger definitely can yield very different results. These are the kind of things referred to as "Heisenbugs."

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in multithreaded apps, attaching a debugger can yield different result.
However, how about the codes which are not related to threads?

I have seen a release build, which has a debugger attached, doesn't have problems. But, when a debugger is not attached, it has problems.
If it is launched first and a debugger is attached to it, it also shows the same problems.